# Decoding weird AutoLayout error message

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift

I am trying to decode this weird AutoLayout error message since yesterday. It is not like anything I found on web. Has anyone ever encountered something this before?

```
2014-06-22 19:04:38.192 TestApp[11117:60b] Objective: {
objective 0x14e79390: <750:1.40743e-07, 250:-43.9999> + 
<250:-1.71827e-08>*UIImageView:0x14d5d780.Width{id: 7} + 
<250:0>*_TtC10TestApp18AutoScaleImageView:0x14d5d6f0.Width{id: 3} + 
<250:-2.64717e-08>*_TtC10TestApp8MainView:0x14e56720.Height{id: 277} + 
<250:5.76127e-08>*_TtC10TestApp8MainView:0x14e56720.Width{id: 275}}
```

Comment: Please post some more information about the error.

Comment: Sounds like you've given some view a set of constraints that can't be satisfied. I'd start by looking at all the constraints on your views.

Answer (score 0):

here is the list of all those scary characters we see sometimes when AutoLayout stops working :)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3-SW1

Good luck!

Comment: what is this, it can go in comments.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: ah ok, sorry guys, I'm just new here. Will be more accurate next time!